# SSO GMail or GDocs with an access_token

Tags: oauth, gmail, saml

Is it possible to perform a SSO via browser to the user gmail inbox or gdocs when the user has already given an authorization via the google apps and we have the access_token?

The idea is the first time the user access to our site we get the user profile from googleapps after the user has authorized us to access it's data, in the scope we have already defined access to gmail and gdocs. The first step is already solved and we have already the access_token and refresh_token in our database (we don't store any password at all) so we can connect offline to the user account using those tokens.

Our idea is to provide a sso mechanism as well so when the user is in our system we want to redirect him/her to his/her gmail inbox without having to enter again his password but using in any way the access_token we initially got.

Is that possible? I read something about saml or the hybrid openid/oauth solution but didn't get any clear message from that.. so anyone could help me? What it would be wonderful is to make a post request to some google login service url with the access_token as parameter and then the user be redirected automatically to it's gmail inbox...

Is it possible to be done?

Answer (score 1):

1. Most users will already be logged into their Google accounts, as they're using these every day for e-mail, calendar, docs and mnore. You should be able to just redirect the user to https://mail.google.com/.  This will work for any users on consumer gmail accounts and will also work for users using the ['new style' Google Apps accounts](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/11/ten-times-more-applications-for-google.html).
2. If your goal is to enable this for users not already logged into their Google accounts, then the Google Apps domain they're using will need to set your service up as their SAML provider, allowing you to authenticate users on their domain.  This is done via the Google Apps Control panel or using the [Admin Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-settings/#managing_single_sign-on_settings). Your application then 'asserts' the identity of the user to Google, and Google logs the user in.  This does use the [SAML service](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/saml_reference_implementation) you referred to.